# Need help for a complicated ACCESS Query

Tags: ms-access

I have the following table:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| date_ac  SERVER_ac  Dept_ac  User_ac  Typeaccess |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1/1/2014 server1    dept1    user1    logon      |
| 1/1/2014 server2    dept3    user2    logon      |
| 1/1/2014 server3    dept3    user2    logoff     |
| 1/1/2014 server1    dept1    user1    logoff     |
| 1/1/2014 server2    dept1    user1    logon      |
| 1/1/2014 server3    dept1    user1    logoff     |
| 2/1/2014 server1    dept1    user1    logon      |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

The table is the record of what is happening on my Terminal server farm. (Several servers). Each time someone logs on or off, a new record is added with the following info:

1. date of the action (log off or log on)
2. server on which the user log on or log off
3. departement of the user
4. user
5. action the user did : log of or log on

So far I was able to give some statistics to the management with the number of users which logged on the farm per departement. Now they are asking for this:

1. average number of people that log each day **per server**: server 1 monday : 200 server 1 tuesday : 350 etc till sunday then server 2 monday etc etc. Knowing that, of course, if someone logs in 5 times the same day it counts for one, and I need only to count the log on. And I want to be able to choose a date range.
2. total of user per day, per week or per month (so we don t care about the server.) Again if a user logs in 10 times per day it counts for one and only count log on.
3. and finally total user but per departement per day/week and month.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What is the format of your log file? if you can convert or export your data to csv then you can play with powershell to sort, group your data.

Comment: If your question is about an Access query, why do you have tags for MySQL and SQL Server? They have nothing to do with (and are not syntax compatible) with Access. Use tags that actually apply to your question, so that it a) gets to the people who can actually answer the question, b) doesn't annoy those users looking for MySQL questions that end up seeing this one, and c) gets classified properly to turn up in search results for future users of this site. Don't just add random tags because you recognize the words.

Comment: These are some pretty simple Group By queries.  If this is "advanced", you might want to take a SQL course.

Comment: I think you will be more likely to receive answers if you scale back the question to one query instead of three.  Pick one and show us the SQL from your best attempt.  Show us the full text of any error message.  If no error, explain the differences between what your query returns and what you need instead.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks the answers. So far i have sucessfull made that quesry : SELECT t1.[dg_0], Count(t1.[user_ac]) AS [UniqueLogins] FROM (SELECT [date_ac],[dg_0],[user_ac] FROM [log_table] WHERE [logon_ac] = 'LOGON' AND [date_ac] BETWEEN #"+$datedebutfinale+"# and #"+$datefinfinale+"# GROUP BY [dg_0],[date_ac],[user_ac]) t1 GROUP BY t1.[dg_0]

Comment: Hi ! Thanks the answers. So far i have sucessfull made that query : SELECT t1.[dg_0], Count(t1.[user_ac]) AS [UniqueLogins] FROM (SELECT [date_ac],[dg_0],[user_ac] FROM [log_table] WHERE [logon_ac] = 'LOGON' AND [date_ac] BETWEEN #"+$datedebutfinale+"# and #"+$datefinfinale+"# GROUP BY [dg_0],[date_ac],[user_ac]) t1 GROUP BY t1.[dg_0]  This return me the nbr of user per dg (department) between 2 dates. my problem is the "day" factor.  I don't see how to do anything with days ... this is my first attempt with queries btw, i am an infra guy not a programmer... thanks !